# JSON processing On hadoop

Tags: java, json, hadoop

I am trying to run map reduce on a json file. The format of the input file is as below.

```
{"Id":1, "title":"A list of SaaS management resources to help kickstart and augment your efforts","category":"business"}
{"Id":2, "title":"All Over the Board: 1Working on a  23 (Temp) Dream","category":"business"}
{"Id":3, "title":"Tulsa Web Design","category":"business"}
```

The expected output of my reduce function is as below.

```
1 business A 1
1 business list 1
1 business of 1
```

Below is the code that i am using to read the json file get the required values and then convert it into string. Word count is done on this string by splitting the string into key values, where key is Id + category + each word in title and value is 1.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.json.*;

public class mr1 {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();


        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

               String title;
                       String Id;
                       String category;
                       String line;
                       String valueLine;

            try {

                    line = value.toString();


                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parser.parse(line));

                    title = (String) obj.get("title");
                    category = (String) obj.get("category");
                    Id = (String) obj.get("Id");

                    title = title.replaceAll("[!?,:()1-9]", "");
                    String[] strs = title.split("\\s+");

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                            for(int i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                                sb.append(strs[i]+" ");
                            }

                    // valueLine  = 1 business Tulsa Web Design

                    valueLine = Id + " " + category + " " + sb.toString();

                    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(valueLine);
                    String IndexAndCategory = "";

                    IndexAndCategory += itr.nextToken() + " ";
                    IndexAndCategory += itr.nextToken() + " ";


                    while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

                        word.set(IndexAndCategory + itr.nextToken());
                        context.write(word, ONE);
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)  
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                int sum = 0;
                for(IntWritable val : values) {     
                    sum += val.get();               
                }

                result.set(sum);
                context.write(key, result);
        }   
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "mr1");
        job.setJarByClass(mr1.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
                job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
                job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }
}
```

I am able to compile the code create the jar file and when i run it on hadoop i was getting the following error.

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1986)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1951)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

The jar files that i am using for this code are as below;

```
1. hadoop-common-2.5.0.jar 
2. json-20160212.jar
3. hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.0.jar
```

I guess the problem is where i am converting the line into JSONObject, but i am not sure about this issue. Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: This is a runtime issue, did you check your CLASSPATH, Do you have those jars in your CLASSPATH

Comment: @Rupesh the way i compiled this code is. javac -classpath jar1:jar2:jar3 mr1.java where jar1, jar2 and jar3 corresponds to jars specified in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my mapper class from the map-reduce job. (the reducer class is same as above).

```
 public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

                private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
                private Text word = new Text();


                public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException, JsonParseException {

                           String title;
                           String id;
                           String cat;
                           String line;
                           String valueLine;
                           Details details = null;

                           line = value.toString();

                           // json object
                           Gson gsoObj = new Gson();
                           details = gsoObj.fromJson(line, Details.class);

                           // values
                           id = details.id;
                           cat = details.category;
                           title = details.title;


                           String final_ = id + " " +  cat + " " + title;

                           final_ = final_.replaceAll("[!?,:()1-9]", "");

                           // valueLine  = 1 business Tulsa Web Design

                           valueLine = final_;

                           StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(valueLine);
                           String IndexAndCategory = "";

                           IndexAndCategory += itr.nextToken() + " ";
                           IndexAndCategory += itr.nextToken() + " ";


                           while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

                            word.set(IndexAndCategory + itr.nextToken());
                            context.write(word, ONE);
                            }

                }

        private class Details {

                        protected String id = "";
                        protected String title = "";
                        protected String category = "";
                }

        }
```

I used gson library [gson-2.3.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson231jar.htm) to process the json data from the json file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have forgotten to add JSon jar in your Hadoop job jar. This may help you: http://tikalk.com/build-your-first-hadoop-project-maven

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE  are you using?

1>If you are using Net-beans Then bind your all libraries in one jar(A fat jar). For that you just have to include some xml code in your bulid.xml file
Here IS a code

```
 <target name="-post-jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="NameOfYourJar"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

2>If You are using Eclipse then it is bit easy

```
Right click the project 
Point to build path
and Export jar with all dependancy
```

Then submit jar to hadoop with proper arguments.It May work.Because all dependency you are binding in one jar.  you dont have to bother about classpath.You can submit that jar from any hadoop installed machine.
(Ignore if you are using maven build)